# Я думаю, что здесь невозможно использовать конструкцию try-with-resources. Что я могу сделать и как?

Tags: java

При использовании конструкции **try-catch-finally** возможна ситуация, когда происходит подавление одного исключения другим.

> Метод **close()** может сгенерировать исключение. 
>   В этот же момент, основной код работы с ресурсом, тоже может выбросить исключение, но его исключение будет утеряно, так как оно будет перезаписано исключением, которое может возникнуть уже в самом блоке **finally** и может возникнуть уже от метода **close()**, при попытке закрытия ресурса, которого нет.
>
> Таким образом , Информация об исходной ошибке пропадёт: мы никогда не узнаем, что было причиной исходного исключения.

Поэтому я решил использовать оператор **try-with-resourse**.
 Ниже приведен класс который создает пул коннекторов из которого и берутся коннекторы.
 Следующий кусок кода показывает первоначальный вариант, а за ним вариант, в котором я попытался использовать оператор **try-with-resourse**.

Остаются вопросы:

1. Как закрывать **resulSet**, в данном случае он может быть помещен в оператор  **try-with-resourse**  и компилятор это пропустит, но код не выполнится, потому что объект **PrepareStatement** не получит данные.
2. Как отменить для конткретного объекта **connection** (для коннектора,который в данный момент используется) транзакцию, так как если я использую открытие ресурса **Connection** в операторе **try-with-resourse**, соответственно я не могу его уже указать в блоке **catch**.

Вот получение **Connection** из пула коннекторов:

```
public class ConnectionPool extends Constants  {

    private static final ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool();

    public static ConnectionPool getPool() {
        return pool;
    }


    private DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionPool() {
        Properties properties;
        String nameJndiResource;
        try {
            if (isBlank(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES_JNDI)) {
                throw new ValidateException(MESSAGE_NOT_EMPTY_STR);
            }

            properties = new ClassPathPropertiesReader().getProperties(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES_JNDI);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(MESSAGE_EXCEPTION_FILE_JNDI, e);
        }

        isNullObjects(properties);

        try {
            nameJndiResource = properties.getProperty(JNDI_LINK);
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context rootContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource) rootContext.lookup(nameJndiResource);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(MESSAGE_LOOKUP_JNDI, e);

        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try  {
            dataSource.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ConnectionException(MESSAGE_CONNECTION, e);
        }
    }


    private void closeDbResources(Connection connection) {
        closeDbResources(connection, null, null);
    }

    private void closeDbResources(ResultSet resultSet) {
        closeDbResources(null, null, resultSet);
    }

    public void closeDbResources(Connection connection, Statement statement) {
        closeDbResources(connection, statement, null);
    }


    private void closeDbResources(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        closeResultSet(resultSet);
        closeStatement(statement);
        closeConnection(connection);
    }


    private void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Connection has not been closed!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeStatement(Statement statement) {
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Statement has not been closed!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: ResultSet has not been closed!");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void rollback(Connection conn) {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Rollback changes as a result of a transaction that failed to undo.");
        }
    }
}
```

Вот кусок кода (пример метода) из dao-класса, здесь используется конструкция
**try-catch-finally**, а также отмена транзакции

```
  @Override
   public List<TranslitEntity> loadAllUserTranslits(Integer userId) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet set = null;

    List<TranslitEntity> result = new ArrayList<TranslitEntity>();

    try {
        connection = ConnectionPool.getPool().getConnection();

        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from   translits WHERE user_id = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, userId);

        set = statement.executeQuery();

        while (set.next()) {
            TranslitEntity entity = ResultSetConverter.createTranslitEntity(set);
            result.add(entity);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        rollback(connection);
        throw new DaoException(e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getPool().closeDbResources(connection, statement, set);
    }

    return result;
}
```

А вот пример попытки использования оператора **try-with-resourse**, но здесь пришлось отказаться от применения отката транзакции в случае возникновения 
исключения и нет возможности закрыть объект **ResultSet**.

```
@Override
public List<TranslitEntity> loadAllUserTranslits(Integer userId) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet set = null;

    List<TranslitEntity> result = new ArrayList<TranslitEntity>();

    try {
        connection = ConnectionPool.getPool().getConnection();

        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from translits WHERE user_id = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, userId);

        set = statement.executeQuery();

        while (set.next()) {
            TranslitEntity entity = ResultSetConverter.createTranslitEntity(set);
            result.add(entity);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        rollback(connection);
        throw new DaoException(e);
    } finally {
        ConnectionPool.getPool().closeDbResources(connection, statement, set);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Например, я использовал конструкцию **`try-with-resources`** для **`connection`** и **`prepareStatement`**, а как быть с откатом транзакции если получилось исключение, куда ее деть?

> **rollback**(connection);

В блоке **`catch`** я не могу его использовать.

Кстати если возникнет вопрос почему я должен закрыть все три объекта : **connection**, **statement**, **resutset**, - недостаточно закрыть **connection**, хотя по документации если закрыть **connection**, то все остальные каналы закроются, на практике бывает не так...
 Поэтому я закрываю все каналы, используемые при работе в рамках одного запроса.

Comment: 1) Это русскоязычный ресурс, и вопросы здесь следует задавать на русском. 2) Пишите подробней, что вы хотите получить и что именно у вас не получается или смущает вас. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 3) Не надо так много кода. Для того, чтобы читать длинный код, нужна мотивация, ее может создать интересный вопрос, но ваша формулировка не мотивирует. Помещайте в вопросе только тот код, который имеет непосредственное отношение к вашему вопросу. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe you mixed up the sites?
https://stackoverflow.com/ is the site where you need to write in English. https://ru.stackoverflow.com - you are here, and here it is necessary to write in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Так как нельзя было применить оператор **'try-with-catch'** (для данного случая), тогда для того, чтобы не было подавления исключения в верхнем блоке, пришлось применить вот такую конструкцию.

```
 private static OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {

    return null;
}

private static void excCheck(){

    OutputStream stream = null;
    Throwable mainException = null;
    try {
        // что-то делаем со stream
        stream = openOutputStream();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        mainException = t;
        // обрабатываем исключение
    } finally {

        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (Throwable unused) {
            /* игнорируем, так как есть основное исключение
             можно добавить лог исключения (по желанию)
            Лог создается, если ресурс не закрылся (например, stream = null).
            Так как закрытие потока невозможно обработать, поэтому нет смысла что-либо
            ловить в данном случае

            Throwable unused - подавит вывод исключения (java.lang.NullPointerException) в StackTrace,
            если объект закрываемого
            ресурса равен null*/
        }
    }
}
```

Вот пример реализации

```
public static void resourcesProcess() {
    OutputStream stream = null;
    Throwable mainException = null;

    try {
        /*
        что-то делаем со stream
         */
        String pathToFile = "c:\\driver";
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
        stream = openOutputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        System.out.println("Блок try");

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        mainException = t;
        /*
         обрабатываем исключение
          */
        System.out.println("Исключение в блоке catch");
        System.out.println("t = " + mainException);
    } finally {

        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (Throwable unused) {
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            System.out.println("Исключение в блоке finally");
        }
    }
}
```

Кроме того, вы всегда можете использовать решение,  с использованием библиотеки Guava 14.0 -  **com.google.common.io.Closer**

кроме того, можно сделать вот так. Здесь можно применить оператор **'try-with-catch'**

```
@Override
public List<TranslitEntity> loadAllUserTranslits(Integer userId) {

    List<TranslitEntity> result = new ArrayList<TranslitEntity>();

    Connection connectionTmp = null;

    try (Connection connection = ConnectionPool.getPool().getConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from translits " +
                 "WHERE user_id = ?");

         ) {
        connectionTmp = connection;
        statement.setInt(1, userId);

    try(ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery()){
        System.out.println("set - " + set);
        System.out.println();
        while (set.next()) {
            TranslitEntity entity = ResultSetConverter.createTranslitEntity(set);
            result.add(entity);
        }
    }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        rollback(connectionTmp);
        throw new DaoException(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```